# How to set Windows background image using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, function, wallpaper

So I want to set the Windows background image using Python.

I have already tried:

```py
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, "absolute path" , 0)
```

But it just turns the background to black.

If anyone needs more information, just ask.

Comment: And if you change the W to A? Is the file a BMP?

Comment: @Anders The file is .png.

Comment: it has to be bmp

Comment: @Anders It still does the same thing